# Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed. No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following **Dockerfile** content

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Install packages needed to run your application (not build deps):

RUN mkdir /code/
WORKDIR /code/
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/

# Install build deps, then run `pip install`, then remove unneeded build deps all in a single step.

COPY ./src scripts /code/

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["/code/entrypoint.sh"]
```

*Removed other lines not related to the question.*

My directory structure in development is

```
\
|- scripts
    |- entrypoint.sh
|- src
    |- # Application files
|- Dockerfile
|- docker-compose.yml
```

The `entrypoint.sh` file is in `scripts/` directory and is being copied to `/code/` in the docker daemon. Same is verified by executing

```
docker run -it my_image ls -la
```

Which lists files as

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Dec 28 19:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Dec 28 19:59 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   545 Dec 28 19:24 Pipfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21517 Dec 28 19:24 Pipfile.lock
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   499 Dec 28 18:47 entrypoint.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   540 Jan  3  2019 manage.py
```

But when I run the image using **docker-compose.yml** (`docker-compose up`) file with content

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my_image:latest
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
    - .:/code/
```

It gives error as

```
ERROR: for myproj_py_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/code/entrypoint.sh\": stat /code/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

The contents of **entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "x$DJANGO_MANAGE_COLLECTSTATIC" = 'xon' ]; then
  echo "Collecting static files"
  python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
  echo "Done: Collecting static files"
fi

if [ "x$DJANGO_MANAGE_MIGRATE" = 'xon' ]; then
  echo "Migrating database"
  python manage.py migrate --noinput
  echo "Done: Migrating database"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `volumes:` declaration hides the contents of `/code` inside the image, including the `/code/entrypoint.sh` script.  When you launch a container Docker constructs a single command from both the entrypoint and command parts combined, so your two containers have combined commands like

```
/code/entrypoint.sh ls -la
/code/entrypoint.sh python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

(Entrypoint scripts typically end with a line like `exec "$@"` that launches the command part to facilitate this pattern.)

In particular you have this problem because the filesystem layouts don't match; you rearrange things in your Dockerfile.  If you were to run

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash -v $PWD:/code image
```

you'd see a `/code/scripts/entrypoint.sh`; if you ran it without the `-v` option you'd see `/code/entrypoint.sh`.

The straightforward solution to this is to delete the `volumes:` directive.  Then Docker Compose will run the code that's actually built into the image, and you won't have this conflict.

Comment: updated question with the content of `entrypoint.sh`. Is it correct?